# Proguard causes AppCompat crash when app loads

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, android-appcompat

I have an android project that works great without Proguard (when minifiy is set to false), when minify is set to true the app crashes as it loads.

I cant figure out what component of the app is being mangled by Proguard,
 the obfuscated stacktrace is below, hopefully it could help.

Please note that my app uses a theme that inherits `Theme.Appcompat.Light.NoActionBar` and that everything works great without proguard enabled. So that exception is probably misleading.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp, PID: 23077
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.activities.LoginActivity}:
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
     at android.support.v7.app.t.a(Unknown Source)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.a(Unknown Source)
     at android.support.v7.app.q.onCreate(Unknown Source)
     at com.myapp.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteIn
```

it.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Any idea what's going on? Any tips on how I can trace the cause of the issue?

Comment: Same to me. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: I've found a bug report, but the "workaround" does not work for me:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=190237